# Question about the topics in SAGA pattern

Tags: events, apache-kafka, saga, event-driven

My question is that, in the compensations flow, they have their own topics or this compensations can be sent to the same topics of the normal/happy flow? I am new to kafka so I am not sure if we could reuse an existing topic of the happy path, just that another partition

I have been searching but cant find any answer about this doubt, or should we have a topic for every possible event?